# PDF Prawn: opening a link in a new tab

Tags: ruby, pdf, hyperlink, prawn

I'm trying to open the following link, that is created in a PDF (which is automatically opened in a browser), in a separate tab - I am using Prawn PDF.

```
  pdf.formatted_text_box [{
    text: t('link'),
    link: @object.attribute.first.link,
    target: '_blank',
    align: :center,
    valign: :center
  }], at: [5, 17], width: 155, height: 25
```

I've tried variations of `target: '_blank'` or `target: :_blank`, but to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks, Nick :)

Comment: I don't think PDFs have the notion of tabs. That's more of a web browser thing.

Comment: Can you provide an example PDF that works this way? (doesn't have to be your own PDF, any PDF will do)

Comment: @Stefan I haven't been able to find a PDF working like this either (or any documentation / examples). Seems like you're right and it is a web browser thing! Thank you! :)